# Standard UIButton isAccessibilityElement returns NO by default

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uiaccessibility

Drag a standard button onto a view in IB and then log its isAccessibilityElement property. This returns NO, even though the documentation [clearly states](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIButton-SW1) that it should be set to YES by default.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My observation has been that if VoiceOver or SwitchControl is enabled then items such as UIButton return YES for -isAccessibilityElement but they *often* return NO otherwise.

I've been unable to identify the circumstances in which they return YES even when an access method (e.g. Voiceover) is not enabled.

EDIT:
It seems that if you enable and then later disable an access method (e.g. Switch Control), `-[UIButton isAccessibilityElement]` will continue returning YES (even across app launches), until the device is rebooted. At least that's how my iPad Pro iOS 9.2 is behaving.